# laravel relationships - 3 way pivot - eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, acl

I am following a tutorial on Laravel ACL, that takes into consideration Users and Roles (https://github.com/laracasts/laravel-5-roles-and-permissions-demo). However, I have an additional level of complexity whereby I need to take into consideration a company model also. So a user may belong to many companies and each instance of a company user may have many roles.

I think the best way to acheive this would use a pivot that has 3 fields:

```
company_id
role_id
user_id
```

Esentially, I want to achive something like this:

```
$user->companyRoles;    //return the user's company roles
$user->company->assignRole('admin'); 
$user->assignRole($companyId, 'admin');
```

Can you advise on the relationships I require to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to develop a SaS(Software as Service) project? I'm asking this to understand the use of the "company_id" field.

Comment: I would go for two pivot tables. One for `role_user`, other for `company_user`.